# compare url with a customized pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

When I scrape web site for articles urls and get all `<a>` tags and get all `href` attributes, this list of urls has some links not for articles but links to other categories or any other pages within same domain so I need to do the following :

create a pattern for the url and match each url in the links list to this pattern so I can know is this url is article url or not

the pattern example is like:

link: "http://www.cnbc.com/2016/03/13/financial-times-china-rebuts-economy-doomsayers-on-debt-and.html"

pattern match: `http://www.cnbc.com/(*)/(*)/(*)/(*).html`

so the idea that replace any variable part of the link with (`*`)

the question is how to match link to pattern?

Comment: Use `[^/]+` instead of `*`, and escape the dot.

Comment: The first three `(*)` sections are numbers, so you can use `[0-9]+`. The last `(*)` section is a combination of letters and symbols, so you can use `.+`.

Comment: I made this pattern for the user who are not programmers so they can't convert the url to regex and this is just example and it is used with any site

Comment: What code do you have and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regular Expression (`regex`) match

You can do this with a [regex match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match).

```
import re

# Example url
url = 'http://www.cnbc.com/2016/03/13/financial-times-china-rebuts-economy-doomsayers-on-debt-and.html'
# Create a regex match pattern
pattern = r'http://www.cnbc.com/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+).html'
# Find match
m = re.match(pattern, url)
# Get Groups
m.groups()
```

---

```
('2016',
 '03',
 '13',
 'financial-times-china-rebuts-economy-doomsayers-on-debt-and')
```

Comment: You should consider replacing the `*` with `+` because it doesn't really make sense to match nothing within the `/` dividers.

Comment: it worked fine and I can also use "\d" with digits instead of (.*) , thanks